# Can I create two seperate user acces on one android application?

Tags: java

I am developing android application on which Student and Faculty can share information and documents that allows access from both Faculty and Student. There would definitely be two users, i.e Student and Faculty. Can I use two seperate user access for Student and Faculty on one application? If so,can guide me on how to do it.

PS: I'm using Firebase as the backend server.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Where are you having difficulty with it?

Comment: Yes, I successfully created the registration part for both Student and Faculty. However, when a student registered to the Firebase, he can access both the Faculty page and the Student page within my application, so that's my problem. I want to seperate those two user access, i.e Student and Faculty, and also I want to put Faculty as the admin so that they can access everything within the application. Can I do this using Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Write your application in at least two parts. First the database back end, doing all the usual CRUD database work.  Second the user-facing front end, which calls methods from the back end.  There will be two types of front end, one for students and one for faculty.  Depending on the type of front end different reports and access to the database will be available.  For example, a student can see a report of her own results.  Faculty can see a bigger report giving all student's results.

I do not know how complex your application will be.  You may need a third Business Logic part that sits between the database back end and the user-facing front end.

Comment: I have no knowlegde about server side coding,that's why I use Firebase. My question is can I create two seperate user access within one application using Firebase? If so, can you guide me on how to do it?

Comment: Create two menus.  The student menu has only the options that students are allowed to access.  The faculty menu has the wider range of options allowed for faculty.  Some options (like "Log Out") will be the same on both menus.  When a user logs in with username and password, you will have a record of whether they are student or faculty.  After a correct login show them the right menu.

Comment: Can I do that using Firebase?

Comment: I am not an expert on Firebase.  Probably yes, but you might need to ask a separate Firebase-specific question.